Wiring Shelly Plus 2PM to control a winch
So I have this winch that is operated by a wired remote. Remote has a rocker switch, on-off-on. Press and hold the switch down, the winch extends.  Press and hold up, it retracts.
I want to wire it for automation, and got a Shelly Plus 2PM for this purpose. I had an idea on how to wire it, but it is not working.
Here is the default setup:
The manual controller has four wires coming into it from the winch; red, white, brown, and black. I believe the red and white are the hot and neutral, and black and brown are control wires. There’s also a capacitor in the controller which connects to the rocker with two 18AWG wires. The other wires are 16AWG.
The rocker switch has six posts on it.
Wire breakdown:
The red wire connects to post 1 on the rocker, and is jumped to post 4 and post 6.
The white wire connects to post 2.
The brown wire connects to post 3 as does wire #1 from the capacitor.
The black wire connects to post 5 as does wire #2 from the capacitor.
Post breakdown:
1 - red wire, jumped to post 4 and post 6
2 - white wire
3 - brown wire, capacitor wire #1
4 - jumped to posts 1, 6
5 - black wire, capacitor wire #2
6 - jumped to posts 1, 4
Controller Testing:

If I disconnect the line from post 4, the up button on the controller will retract the cable, but the down button does nothing.
If I disconnect the brown/capacitor #1 wires from post 5, neither up nor down does anything.
If I disconnect the line from post 6, the down button on the controller will extend the cable, but the up button does nothing.
If I disconnect the black/capacitor #2 wires from post 3, the down button will extend the cable, but the up button does nothing.

The Shelly has a neutral in, two line in, two outputs O1 and O2, and two switches S1 and S2. The manual says to connect power to both lines in.
Theory:
So I thought I could just power up the Shelly and connect its O1 to post 3 and O2 to post 5. Then configure the device in the app to function as a momentary switch.
Results:
When I do this, the Shelly operates as expected, but the winch does not respond as expected. It makes a noise like it’s trying to do something, but it does not extend or retract the cable. It will still operate normally via the controller.
Questions:

Am I wiring this wrong?
Do I need to connect the neutral from the Shelly to post 2 on the rocker switch?
Is the Shelly robust enough to handle the circuit?
Should I be using the switches on the Shelly, S1 and S2?
How can I achieve my aim with either this setup or some other WiFi switch?

Thank you!





Hello and welcome.  Can I suggest you post details of what the switch is connected to, as right now we only have half the picture.  And if you draw the circuit diagram, that's so much better than trying to describe what connects to what in words.

I literally did that. It’s connected to a winch.

@Korzak That's not details. Details would be along the lines of "it draws this much stall current, this much no-load current, this much operating current, it runs at this nominal voltage, it has these filtering elements on it, it's hooked up as shown in this schematic" and so on. Does your switch have to handle full operating current, or is it only acting as a signal? If it's a signal, what are the exact requirements for it? Does the switch need to be debounced? There are many details you've left out, and that's what jonathanjo is asking for. "A winch" is not enough.

the pin numbering scheme is inconsistent ... if red is 1 and white is 2, then how can brown be 3?
